# How to deal with persistent off-topics posts about the same thing?

Tags: feature-request, off-topic

Recently on [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) there have been many posts regarding modded minecraft technical support, which is clearly not in the scope.

Yes, we always comment that we vote the question to close, but since it is getting too frequent I believe it should be taken care of, possibly in the form of a feature that warns before you post the question, or a confirmation box if the site finds both words "mod" and "crash" in the body of the question.

Comment: This seems to be relevant only to [gaming.SE], should it be moved? We will never have a `minecraft-forge` and `crash` tag on SO, those tags will be too broad.

Comment: The fundamental problem as written in the title could apply to other sites, @UniformsForSale; the Minecraft bit is not essential. This isn't inappropriate here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As most of those questions are probably tagged *Minecraft,* you could try asking for a [tag warning](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14237/145802), i.e., a special warning that is shown to everybody asking a question and tagging it *Minecraft.*

It’s not as in-your-face as what you are asking for, but probably easier to implement.

Comment: Coming back to this, how do I ask for a tag warning? Is there a page or should some developers come across this when they have time?

Comment: In your case: [Ask a question on Meta Arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) tagged *feature-request* along the lines of “Do we want a tag warning for Minecraft and how should it be worded?” You can take the general explanation of tag warnings and other inspiration from [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14237/145802). Do not forget to explain what issues you want to address with this. In my experience it’s best to suggest a procedure right ahead; look [here](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/2353/19174) for inspiration.